# Arrays. Histograms, dividing array into subset and counting number of elements in each group. Java

Tags: java, arrays, histogram

Hi im really confused abt this method which i have to create.
I have to create a histogram array with num division categories i.e selecting a reasonable integer range and step size for numdivisons to cover whole range of elements in an array.  @return array histogram in which position i contains the 
* number of observations in division i
*/

example:
{1,3,4,5,10,15,17}.

If numdivisions=2 then we need to divide the range (1 to 17) into 2 divisions.
For example, range 0 to 10 (not included) and 10 to 20. 
In this case there are 4 values in the range 0 to <10 and 3 values between 10 and 20.
This histogram for numdivisions=2 would be the array {4,3}.

public int[] histogram(int numdivisions)
can anyone tell me what would be the best method of doing it? thanks

Comment: for my understanding of the task, you need to create a division, where the number of elements in all sub-arrays are equal (+-1 if size%partitions != 0) am I correct?

Comment: no i dont think so.. it means it means if a user inputs numdivsions then we have to create a stepsize in which each of our elements fall into. eg. {1,2,3,4,56} and the numdivisons is say 3. then the step size would be 1-3 and 4-56. thus the new array would be {3,2} i.e how many elements fall into each step size. do u get what i mean? :o

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

1. Get the minimum and maximum elements of your array
2. Take the difference and divide it by num, obtaining "step"
3. Now iterate through the array, placing the number n in the slot i such that i * step <= n - min < (i+1) * step

Comment: yes. thanks. can u please try to explain what u did in step3? i mean where did the n come from? is n the number of elements?

Comment: "n" is the current element you are iterating upon.